# Angular JS with jQuery plugin in Supersized

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, supersized

Anyone managed to integrated supersize with angular js?

I tried creating a directive and placing the following code inside a directive

```
$.supersized({ 
      //params :
```

supersize did work in creating the

```
<ul id=supersized" .... >
```

However my screen isn't displaying supersize's full screen slideshow. Any idea why?

Comment: I switched over to responsiveslides.js [http://responsiveslides.com/] , it will work.

Comment: Please create a pluncker with some code that you've tried

Comment: try wrapping it in `$timeout` in directive